# jquery slidedown causing elements to simply appear

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I am trying to get the slideDown() method to work, but it never seems to work for me.  I can do FadeIn and FadeOut just fine.  I put together some sample code to show what's happening to me:

http://jsfiddle.net/berwzq54/1/

If you click the button, it just appears.  No animation.  I would like it to slide.  Can anyone explain why it's behaving like that instead of sliding?

Thanks!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnAdjustTime" class="btn btn-warning" value="Adjust Time" onclick="$('#tblAdjustTime').slideDown(500);" />
<table id="tblAdjustTime" style="width:100%;display:none;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Enter a note:</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="txtNote" class="form-control" style="height:150px;" placeholder="Explain any clock in/out mistakes here..." onkeydown="return funTrapEnterPress();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label id="lblAdjustTimeLabel" runat="server">When should your clock IN be?</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      &nbsp;
      <table class="table" style="width:100%;background-color:transparent;">
        <tr>
          <td class="CenterVertically">
            <label>Date:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-group date" style="width:125px;">
              <input id="txtAdjustedDate" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control form-control-condensed" maxlength="10" />

              <span class="input-group-addon form-control-condensed"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="CenterVertically">
            <label>Time:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="txtAdjustedTime" runat="server" class="form-control" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table's height cannot be changed - it just grows to be the size of it's content so as jQuery `slideDown` relies on animating the height, it won't work.

Just wrap your table in a span and animate that:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnAdjustTime" class="btn btn-warning" value="Adjust Time" onclick="$('#divAdjustTime').slideDown(500);" />
<div id="divAdjustTime" style="display:none;">
  <table id="tblAdjustTime" style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Enter a note:</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="txtNote" class="form-control" style="height:150px;" placeholder="Explain any clock in/out mistakes here..." onkeydown="return funTrapEnterPress();" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label id="lblAdjustTimeLabel" runat="server">When should your clock IN be?</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        &nbsp;
        <table class="table" style="width:100%;background-color:transparent;">
          <tr>
            <td class="CenterVertically">
              <label>Date:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-group date" style="width:125px;">
                <input id="txtAdjustedDate" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control form-control-condensed" maxlength="10" />

                <span class="input-group-addon form-control-condensed"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="CenterVertically">
              <label>Time:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input id="txtAdjustedTime" runat="server" class="form-control" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pete!  So simple!  Now I know a very important rule about HTML.  :-)

Comment: Glad it helped - I try not to use tables because they aren't very responsive and should only be used for tabular data (which forms can be classed as), plus they aren't very "style-able"

Comment: I hear that a lot about Tables.  But as you said, virtually every app I make (internal apps only) uses tabular data.  So I use tables everywhere.  I don't do much style with them, other than alternating row colors and a hover highlight.  
Every time I start a new app, I try to learn & do something new.  This time, I'm getting into animating things (but not too much) to make it feel more modern.  ;-)

Comment: haha nice, if you use a lot of tables and jquery, you might want to have a look at https://datatables.net/, decent plugin that does a lot of table manipulation out of the box

Comment: Wow, looks really cool!  My only fear is that I will spend a bunch of time learning it and getting it implemented, only to find out some deal-breaking limitation.  I have gotten my programming down to a science...where I have a HUGE knowledge base that I made myself & I can just copy & paste code and change things up as needed.  That website has an "Editor" version, which would be needed 90% of the time for my apps, but it costs.  So once again, I'm afraid to spend time & effort, and now money, to learn there's a limitation.  :-/  I'll have to examine it more closely later.  Thanks again!